# Maven Failsafe not picking up testng test suite, but Surefire does

Tags: java, maven, testng

A bit of a newbie here, but I'm trying to use the Maven Failsafe plugin to run TestNG tests in my Java project using the Maven task in TFS 2015. I originally used the Surefire plugin but wanted to use Failsafe instead, and when changing the code slightly according to [documentation for TestNG](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/testng.html), the Failsafe plugin will run the TestNG test class instead of the test suite (and fail because I'm using parameters). When switching back to Surefire, the tests run as a test suite and pass.

I've tried different versions of Failsafe and that hasn't changed anything. Is there anything that I'm missing that Failsafe needs to recognize a test suite?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(with Surefire)

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(testng.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <parameter name="urlsource" value="https://httpbin.org/get"></parameter>
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.java.TestGenericRESTAPI"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: surefire and failsafe are supposed to share the same code. Is surefire-2.19.1 working? Is failsafe-2.13 failing?

Comment: Surefire-2.13 works for me, but Failsafe 2.13 doesn't. It looks like surefire-2.19.1 works fine but failsafe-2.19.1 doesn't. (I also added in skipAfterFailureCount and surefire failed correctly while failsafe succeeded). I'm not sure now if this is an issue for just me if I'm not able to get failsafe to work for different versions.

Comment: Did you notice failsafe, by default, is not failing the build (goal `integration-test`) but you have to run the goal `verify` if you want to fail the build?

Comment: Hmm, neither seemed to make a difference for failsafe.

Comment: Do you have the dependency for testng, I presume yes?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration didn't run Failsafe for me at all, only Surefire. As per [Failsafe docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html), I configured goals:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now both Surefire and Failsafe execute tests on `mvn verify` (and Failsafe passes parameters correctly). If you want to skip Surefire tests, you can do this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now Surefire still runs on `mvn verify`, but doesn't actually run any tests. I don't know how to disable Surefire completely, so any suggestions or improvements are welcome.

Note that your IDE may still invoke Surefire directly (NetBeans does for me). Some IDE-specific settings may help here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Looks like it still calls the class. :(

Comment: @Sachi, did you call `mvn verify` directly from command line? Because the problem may be in your TFS configuration (just like NetBeans is doing how its pleases in my case).

Comment: Did you have any test suites when you tested? It looks like Failsafe can run for me but for some reason, it still calls the class instead of the suite.

Comment: @Sachi, well I just took your suite example, that's it. And I had a single class with a single test method for which I declared `@Parameters` just to check that the parameter is passed all right. Can you post an MVCE? The minimum complete pom required, and the minimum test class, so anybody can just copy-paste everything in the right files and run it? Mention the relative paths of all files inside the project dir, too.